# Eliminating rows with 0 values in R

Tags: r, multiple-columns

I have subsetted the two columns I want from my data set as below:

```
hum <- weight.egg[,c("H_Weight", "H_Egg_Number")]
```

I now want to remove all those rows (for both columns) that contain a 0 value. Say if one row in one of the columns contains a 0, I want to eliminate the corresponding value in the other column from the set as well.

e.g. H_Weight = 0.22 and H_Egg_Number = 0 <-- I want to eliminate this whole row from the study

Can anybody help?

Comment: `hum <- weight.egg[weight.egg$H_Weight!=0 & weight.egg$H_Egg_Number!=0,c("H_Weight", "H_Egg_Number")]` I suggest to read on basics of R.

Answer (score 1):

You can try

```
hum[!rowSums(!hum),]
#        H_Weight H_Egg_Number
#1   1.37095845            3
#3   0.36312841            3
#4   0.63286260            3
#6  -0.10612452            2
#7   1.51152200            1
#8  -0.09465904            3
#9   2.01842371            1
#10 -0.06271410            3
```

Or as suggested by @David Arenburg

```
hum[rowSums(hum == 0) < 1, ]
```

#### data

```
set.seed(42)
hum <- data.frame(H_Weight=rnorm(10), H_Egg_Number=sample(0:3,10,replace=TRUE))
```

Comment: The classis solution, but I think `hum[rowSums(hum == 0) < 1, ]` is a bit more readble

Comment: @David Arenburg Thanks for the input.  Yes, it is more readable.  I will update.

Answer (score 0):

```
hum <- hum[which(hum$H_Weight != 0 & hum$H_Egg_Number != 0), ]
```

In this case which will return a vector with the indices of the rows that satisfy your condition.
Then you select only those rows by passing the result of which to [,]

Try ?which from the command line to learn more about this command. Note the use of '&' instead of '&&'